# setState is not updating when appending new state

Tags: reactjs

I am making react-beautiful-dnd and I want to create a column by clicking a button. after clicking the button the state wont update.
It gives the correct state when I console.log(newState), but console.log(this.state) is still the original state.

```
    //My state

    state = {
            tasks: {
                'task-1': {
                    id: 'task-1',
                    content: 'task-1'
                }
            },
            columns: {
                'column-1': {
                    id: 'column-1',
                    title: 'column-1',
                    taskIds: ['task-1', 'task-2', 'task-3', 'task-4'],
                },
            },
            columnOrder: ['column-1'],
        };

    // SETTING STATE

    handleClick = () => {
            const newState = {
                ...this.state,
                columns: {
                    ...this.state.columns,
                    ['column-4']: {
                        id: 'column-4',
                        title: 'column-4',
                        taskIds: [],
                    }
                }
            }
            this.setState(newState)
        }

    // Button

            <Button
                onClick={this.handleClick}
            >
                Add
            </Button>
```

Comment: you need to call setState like this

Comment: Update Your handleClick  as `this.setState(...newState)`

Comment: It should be `this.setState(newState);` like how you wrote already in onDragEnd method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to bind your `handleClick` function to the component's context in the components constructor:

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

Comment: my Component does't have a constructor

Comment: Could you share the whole component file?

Comment: I found what is wrong I console.log(this.state) immediately in the handleClick function and where it has't update the state yet. Thanks